# error in transferring file using tcp in java

Tags: java, file, tcp

I am developing a web app using `jsp` in which i use a `tcp connection` to send a file from server to a client. But while doing so, the program goes into an infinite loop.
 It doesn't return anything. Can anyone please help me?

I am posting the server and client code here.

Server code:

```
byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
sendData = "FILE".getBytes();
DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 5006);
clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
sendData = file.getBytes();
sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 5006);
clientSocket.send(sendPacket);

ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5494);
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

File transferFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Krishna\\Documents\\LanMan\\" + file);
byte[] bytearray = new byte[(int) transferFile.length()];
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(transferFile);
BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
bin.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
os.write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);

DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
String a = (new String(receiveData, "UTF-8")).trim();
//if(a.equals())
os.flush();
//bin.close();
socket.close();
serverSocket.close();
```

Client code:

```
if (a.startsWith("FILE")) {
    byte b[] = new byte[1024];

    received = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
    serversocket.receive(received);
    a = (new String(receiveData, "UTF-8")).trim();

    int filesize = 2022386;
    int bytesRead;
    int currentTot = 0;
    socket = new Socket(ip, 5494);
    byte[] bytearray = new byte[filesize];
    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\LanMan\\" + a);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    bytesRead = is.read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.length);
    currentTot = bytesRead;

    do {
        bytesRead = is.read(bytearray, currentTot, (bytearray.length - currentTot));
        if (bytesRead >= 0) currentTot += bytesRead;
    } while (bytesRead > -1);

    bos.write(bytearray, 0, currentTot);
    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
    //fos.close();
    //is.close();

    sendData = "OK".getBytes();
    DatagramPacket send = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, ip, port);
    serversocket.send(send);
    socket.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You implemented a deadlock.

The server writes the file content, then wait for a datagram packet from the client, the closes the socket.

The client reads until the server closes the socket, then sends a datagram packet.

So each party is waiting for the other one.

Also, never ignore the result of the InputStream.read() method like you're doing in the server code. You can never assume that all the file will be read in one single call.

Comment: Thank you for that. I just closed the socket before sending and receiving packets in client and server respectively. But now, there is a new problem. The program worked well for small files(less than 1mb). When i tried for a file sized 5mb, it becomes still.